# firing multiple commands in StackExchange.Redis causes large memory consumption

Tags: memory-leaks, stackexchange.redis

Given this scenario

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(1);
foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0,5000000))
{
    db.StringIncrement("K:"+x, 1, StackExchange.Redis.CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
}
```

memory consumption has a rapid peak reaching about 300MB and at the end of the process is not been released. If I then force a GC.Collect command it drops returning to starting level. This is an issue because when I add more commands inside the loop the memory consumption grows even larger, obviously causing out of memory in a 32bit process. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: same observations using transactions with Execute(FireAndForget). Without it memory is OK but it's slower. I have not checked but I suspect that requests accumulate faster then can be delivered and this is why.